# ptxas "double is not supported" warning when using thrust::sort on a struct array

Tags: c++, c, cuda, thrust

I'm trying to sort an array of structs on my GPU with thrust::sort. However, when I compile with nvcc, I get this warning:

ptxas /tmp/tmpxft_00005186_00000000-5_antsim.ptx, line 1520; warning : Double is not supported. Demoting to float

I've isolated the problem to my call to thrust::sort, here:

```
thrust::sort(thrustAnts, thrustAnts + NUM_ANTS, antSortByX());
```

thrustAnts is an array of Ant structs located on the GPU, while antSortByX is a functor as defined below:

```
typedef struct {
   float posX;
   float posY;
   float direction;
   float speed;
   u_char life;
   u_char carrying;
   curandState rngState;
} Ant;

struct antSortByX {
   __host__ __device__ bool operator()(Ant &antOne, Ant &antTwo) {
      return antOne.posX < antTwo.posX;
   }
};
```

It seems to me as though there aren't any doubles in this, though I'm suspicious the less-than operator in my functor evaluates those floats as doubles. I can solve this problem by compiling with -arch sm_13, but I'm curious as to why this is complaining at me in the first place.

Comment: How did you isolate the issue to the `thrust::sort()` call? I'm wondering if the compiler is optimizing out some DP logic elsewhere. If thrust silently promotes floats to doubles, it could seriously hurt performance on GPUs which do support DP but at a fraction of the throughput of SP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The demotion happens because CUDA devices support double precision calculations at first with compute capability 1.3. NVCC knows the specifications and demotes every double to float for devices with CC < 1.3 just because the hardware cannot handle double precisions.

A good feature list could be found on wikipedia: [CUDA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA#Version_features_and_specifications)

That you can’t see any doubles in this code doesn't mean that they are not there. Most commonly this error results from a missing `f` postfix on a floating point constant. The compiler performance an implicit cast from all floats to double when one double is part of the expression. A floating point constant without the `f` is a double value and the casting starts. However, for the less-operator a cast without constant expressions should not happen.

I can only speculate, but it seems to me that in your case a double precision value could be used within the thrust::sort implementation. Since you provide only a user function to a higher order function (functions that take functions as parameters).

Comment: this doesn't answer the question. the question is where the doubles come from in the first place, not why the compiler is demoting them

Comment: @kronos: Odd as it is, it seems that thrust::sort does indeed use doubles. Here's the kicker though: if I add a device function that uses doubles, it doesn't complain about that. Even if I say something like float x = 0.0; there's not a word from the compiler.